# In iOS, play local download m3u8 video files, must set up an HTTP server? Have the method does not need to set up the HTTP server？

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, http-live-streaming

I now have a project that needs to be m3u8 files downloaded to the local, to play， now have a solution is through the local HTTP service to create play m3u8 files already downloaded，Is there a kind of do not need to set up local HTTP service, to play local m3u8 files

Comment: Don't download m3u8, just store their URL and open them with `AVPlayer`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use direct link for play M3U8 files using this code,

```
NSString * urlStr = //your URL
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];


- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   //Called when playback complete
}
```

Or you can use `NSURL` method `fileURLWithPath:` to create file URL.